# Can we restrict number of indexers for set operator in indexers?

Tags: c#

For below indexer it should be in such a way that for get{} user can pass employeeid or firstname and for set{} can pass only employeeid.

Here is the code:

```
public Employee this[int employeeid = 0,string firstname = ""]
{
    get
    {
        if (employeeid != 0)
        {
            return Employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.No == employeeid);
        }
        else
        {
            return Employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.FirstName == firstname);
         }
    }
    set
    {
        if (employeeid == value.No)
        {
            Employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.No == employeeid).FirstName = value.FirstName;
            Employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.No == employeeid).LastName = value.LastName;
        }
        else
        {
            ArgumentException argEx = new ArgumentException("Falied to update");
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(argEx.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to know is there any syntax that will restrict the number and type of indexers passed at set operations.
Or simply add new indexer for set which obviously works.

Answer (score 3):

Add a new indexer. C# added indexers to provide an array-like syntax with user-defined semantics. The semantics that your code provides is counterintuitive, and not at all array-like.

For example, `employee[123, "Alex"]` and `employee[123, "Bart"]` will return the same `Employee`, because ID wins when both ID and a name are present. This would be an OK thing to do for a properly named method, for example

```
Employee GetEmployeeByIdOrName(int employeeid = 0,string firstname = "") {
    ...
}
```

A multi-parameter indexer is expected to treat the entire combination of arguments as a single key, which your implementation does not do.

> For example if a functions is having two parameters `int` and `string`. Then if user can give `int` or `string` but not both. Don't you think we need a new function syntax that makes this possible.

You can do it today with a pair of overloads calling the same method:

```
// The following two methods are visible to users of your object
public Employee GetEmployee(int id) {
    return GetEmployeeByIdOrName(id, null);
}
public Employee GetEmployee(string name) {
    return GetEmployeeByIdOrName(0, name);
}
// This private method provides an implementation
private Employee GetEmployeeByIdOrName(int employeeid, string firstname) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: filed under "just because you can, doesnt mean you should"

Comment: OK parameters will be common for set and get. And there is only functionality of optional parameters and not restricting parameters. For example if a functions is having two parameters int and string. Then if user can give int or string but not both. Don't you think we need a new function syntax that makes this possible. Indexers and functions are different but regarding parameters partially similar. So I am raising this question.

Comment: @NithinB You need to use method overloading which is convenient to your case that optional parameters.

Comment: @NithinB I edited the answer to respond to your comment, please take a look.

Comment: I can achieve it simply writing this in case of functions Function1(int firstNumber = 0, string secondNumber = null). But there is no restriction for user to pass number of parameters like can pass 1st parameter or 2nd paramater but not both parameters. I want to restrict user giving 2 paramaters like an compile time error.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use different parameters for setter and getter in the same Indexer.

To be Honest, i see what you're trying to do as totally unclear to the developers using your class.

I would not use indexers to find objects inside an array inside a class by id or by name in the same method.

Why don't you just split than into two methods (indexers) for each search criteria:

```
public Employee this[int employeeid]
{
    get
    {
        return Employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.No == employeeid);
    }
}

public Employee this[string firstname]
{
    get
    {
        return Employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.FirstName == firstname);
    }
}
```

Your `Set` indexer is completely unclear and misleading. You check if the passed object has the same ID as the object you're calling the indexer method on and then update that values from the passed ones. Not to mention that you're updating only two properties in that object. This is a poor design while an alternative clear solution would be:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(Employee updatedEmployee)
{
    if (this.No == updatedEmployee?.No)
    {
        this.FirstName = updatedEmployee.FirstName;
        this.LastName = updatedEmployee.LastName;
    }
    else
    {
        // throw
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I know there are lot of possibilities to implement like adding new indexer or functions. But cant we declare indexer something like public string this[(set)(get)int x, (get)String y]. Which means get{} can be called by both parameters and set{} by only 1st parameter. I think this type of syntax will make the coding smaller and more flexible to use.

Comment: @NithinB No you can't. This is stated in the answer that you can't separate the getter's parameters from the setter's parameters

Comment: @NithinB Also, splitting the indexers makes it explicit and clear what your intent is. Which is better anyway. You should always choose clarity over fancy stuff.